# How to detect if an element is covered/overlapped by another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem that I want to detect if an element is covered by another one in one page.

eg:

```
DOM elements
<div class="ele ele1"><p>A</p></div>
<div class="ele ele2"><p>B</p></div>
<div class="ele ele3"><p>C</p></div>
<div class="cover"><p>D</p></div>


CSS style
.ele{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
}
p{   
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.ele1{
  background-color: red;
}
.ele2{
  background-color: blue;
}
.ele3{
  background-color: green;
}
.cover{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   left: 300px;
   top: 10px;
   background: grey;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/veraWei/6v89b1fy/

How to detect element A is not been covered but element C is covered by ele D?
One more thing: the number of "D" is uncertain. Maybe there are E/F/G... in the page.
I appreciate all the thoughts or existing examples/jQuery plugins/CSS/etc.

Thanks all your guys' detailed answers. But I need more shortly explanation maybe one attribute that indicate that A is not covered by any elements and C is covered by rendering. Is there any plugin or attribute existing?

Comment: not understand the question. what do you mean by covered? do you mean overlapping the element?

Comment: you mean c is covered by d?

Comment: sorry, I updated the edit. A, B, C, D are just an symbols, I mean how to detect there is an element called D beyond the area of C that we cannot see the fully area? But We can see all the pixel of A and B.

Comment: The answer of this question is going to be very complex if you want to check whether the element is covered by any other element from left or right or top or bottom..

Comment: `var coverLeft = $(".cover").offset().left;
if (coverLeft >= $(".ele3").offset().left &&
    coverLeft <= $(".ele3").offset().left + $(".ele3").width()) {
    console.log("element C is (horizontal)covered")
}`

Comment: @魏秋明 have you checked my answer? its working 100%. check my answer please and then tell if anything is wrong.

Comment: @Rohit Thanks for coding here. But I think loop all the eles is not the most appropriate way. In the real case, it will be a lot of elements and all them are dynamic. So I need most is whether their is an attribute that indicate the element is covered or not, and the attribute will return true or false?

Comment: @魏秋明 I don't think there would be a way without using `if-else` statements (using offsets comparison)

Comment: @魏秋明 there is no such inbuilt attribute which will tell you an element is covered or not, you have to go through this way detecting whether the element is covered or not and then, if you want, add an attribute to the element which will return true or false..

Comment: @魏秋明 if looping is the problem then you can combine all the conditions in one single `if` - `else`, then check the edit I've made in my answer..

Answer (score 29):

Why not try the following :

1) Find the element position relative to the viewport:

```
rect=elt.getBoundingClientRect();
x=rect.left;
y=rect.top;
```

(or may be consider the midpoints coordinates)

2) Find the top element at position x, y:

```
topElt=document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
```

3) Check if the top element is the same than the original element :

```
if(elt.isSameNode(topElt)) console.log('no overlapping');
```

Comment: I think this is elegant, modern and cpu efficient answer.

Comment: After some research the `document.elementFromPoint()` status is still Experimental technology. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint

Comment: Also the usage of `isSameNode()` looks like not really cross-browser compatible. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode

Comment: Think you should also check for child elements. E.g. when you have `<ul>` as `elt`, you will most probably have `<li>` as `topElt`, so the condition should be `if (elt.isSameNode(topElt) || elt.contains(topElt) console.log('no overlapping');`

Comment: Flex box is not aware of child wrapping. So even if the children elements are wrapped and not overlapping the target element, the parent can still overlap the target element even though there is no element there overlapping.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/6v89b1fy/4/

```
var coverElem = $(".cover");
var elemArray = [];
elemArray.push($(".ele1"), $(".ele2"), $(".ele3"));

for(i=0; i< elemArray.length; i++)
{
    var currElemOffset = elemArray[i].offset();
    var currElemWidth = elemArray[i].width();

    var currElemStPoint = currElemOffset.left ;
    var currElemEndPoint = currElemStPoint + currElemWidth;


    if(currElemStPoint <= coverElem.offset().left &&  coverElem.offset().left <=  currElemEndPoint)
    {
        elemArray[i].append("<span>Covered</span>");
    }
    else
    {
        elemArray[i].append("<span>Not covered</span>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, for the certain number of elements, the above code is worked. But I think my request is uncertain-number's elements.

Comment: In that case you will have to group base elements in one collection and cover elements in other collection. Now each element from 1st group has to be checked against each and every element present in covered element collection. You can tweak above code very easily to enable that. Please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: This method doesn't catch all possible ways for 'covering' something, for example https://jsfiddle.net/2kr1s5r5/ The one on the right is incorrectly labelled as not covered.

Comment: @ DrunkWolf - Yes...you are absolutely correct. This is not the full fledged code. But yes..this code can be utilized as a starting point for further development. Here on SO we are just to help and not to provide full solution.

Comment: This will not handle the cases when `z-index` is set for elements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick example of how you may go about doing it. This would check for **both** vertical and horizontal overlapping. This is kind of generic and not-so-generic as well since this is based off the HTML in your question. Adjust the top/left values of the `.cover` to see it work for all possible cases.

```js
var $cover = $(".cover"),
  cWidth = $cover.width(),
  cHeight = $cover.height(),
  cLeft = $cover.offset().left,
  cRight = $(window).width() - (cLeft + cWidth),
  cTop = $cover.offset().top,
  cBtm = $(window).height() - (cTop + cHeight);

$("div:not(.cover)").each(function() {

  var $this = $(this),
    eleWidth = $this.width(),
    eleHeight = $this.height(),
    eleLeft = $this.offset().left,
    eleTop = $this.offset().top,
    eleRight = $(window).width() - (eleLeft + eleWidth),
    eleBtm = $(window).height() - (eleTop + eleHeight);

  if (
    cLeft < (eleLeft + eleWidth) &&
    cRight < (eleRight + eleWidth) &&
    cTop < (eleTop + eleHeight) &&
    cBtm < (eleBtm + eleHeight)
  ) {
    alert($this.text() + " is covered by " + $cover.text());
  }
});
```

```css
.ele {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.ele1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.ele2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.ele3 {
  background-color: green;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 60px;
  top: 110px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ele ele1">
  <p>A</p>
</div>
<div class="ele ele2">
  <p>B</p>
</div>
<div class="ele ele3">
  <p>C</p>
</div>
<div class="ele ele3">
  <p>D</p>
</div>
<div class="ele ele3">
  <p>E</p>
</div>
<div class="ele ele3">
  <p>F</p>
</div>
<div class="ele ele3">
  <p>G</p>
</div>
<div class="cover">
  <p>COVER</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for coding here. But I think loop all the eles is not the most appropriate way. In the real case, it will be a lot of elements and all them are dynamic. So I need most is whether their is an attribute that indicate the element is covered or not, and the attribute will return true or false?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've gone through ***all cases of overlapping*** and have *created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ndw8gj/1/)*. I've used `getBoundintClientRect()` and have used it to get `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` values of two `div`s on which overlapping is to be checked and then I've compared the offsets using various conditional statements and conditions too which you'll find below. In the fiddle all your four elements are having `position: absolute`, adjust their `top` and `left` values to make them overlap one another and to check whether two elements are overlapping or not? pass the two elements in the function -

```
checkElements(elA, elB); // pass two elements to check
```

which is in the very last.

You will see the long `if` `else` conditions in the fiddle, they are just for testing all possibilities of overlapping. Here is that **all possible conditions used to check overlapping** -

```
if((eleB.top >= eleA.top && eleB.top <= eleA.bottom) || (eleB.bottom >= eleA.top && eleB.bottom <= eleA.bottom)) {
    if((eleB.left >= eleA.left && eleB.left <= eleA.right) || (eleB.right >= eleA.left && eleB.right <= eleA.right)) {
        el1.innerHTML = '<p>covered</p>';
    }
    else {
        el1.innerHTML = '<p>not covered</p>';
    }
}
else {
    el1.innerHTML = '<p>not covered</p>';
}
```

*You will also see if B overlaps A then it will write A is covered because I've compared using x and y coordinates of A and B.* In this case, I think an additional condition checking `z-index` will be used. I've not created for that.

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ndw8gj/1/), and adjust `top` and `left` values of different elements and then pass two elements in the function `checkElements()` and see the result is correct or not.

You can also do all the checking simultaneously as -

```
checkElements(elA, elB); // check if A is overlapped by B
checkElements(elB, elC); // check if B is overlapped by C
checkElements(elC, elD); // check if C is overlapped by D
```

*See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ndw8gj/2/) using the multiple checking.*

**EDIT:** If looping is the problem, then you can combine all the loops of `if` `else` into a single `if` `else` like this -

```
if(((eleB.top >= eleA.top && eleB.top <= eleA.bottom) || (eleB.bottom >= eleA.top && eleB.bottom <= eleA.bottom)) && ((eleB.left >= eleA.left && eleB.left <= eleA.right) || (eleB.right >= eleA.left && eleB.right <= eleA.right))) {
    el1.innerHTML = '<p>covered</p>'; // or your code of adding true to the attribute that tells about overlapping
}
else {
    el1.innerHTML = '<p>not covered</p>';
}
```

*[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8ndw8gj/4/)*

Comment: Ok, I understand. it's bad that there is no such inbuilt attribute. Maybe I should consider another way to solve the problem in the real project. Thanks very much.