# How to determine the real visibility of an element?

Tags: javascript, html

How to use JS to determine the real visibility of an element?

For example, there is the following demo

```css
.red{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
.blue{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 60px;
  top: 60px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
.green{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='red'></div>
<div class='blue'></div>
<div class='green'></div>
```

How can I check that the "blue" element is not visible on the screen?
Is there a way to determine the real visibility of an element at a given time to the human eye?
Same question with z-index. checking all elements and comparing which z-index is not an option, of course, and the elements can be in different positions.

Comment: You mean within the scope of the document viewport?

Comment: Why you need that kind of info? Maybe if you put elements in page yourself, maybe then you can clearly know what and when is hidden and work around it?

Comment: You will need to give more details on your real use case. What shape are your elements?  Are they inside a div? Do you need to test, if the element is off screen? Etc.

Comment: Your question now is too complicated. E.g. you have some parent element with `width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden` or `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden` or `color: transparent; background-color: transparent;`

Comment: There's also [javascript - How to detect if an element is covered/overlapped by another one? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713250/how-to-detect-if-an-element-is-covered-overlapped-by-another-one)